Inconsistent Rendering of Nested Parentheses in Efficalc (python package): Is Using brackets the Recommended Approach?
I've been using Efficalc for generating HTML representations of mathematical expressions and encountered a recurring issue where nested parentheses are not displayed correctly, especially when involving multiplication operations. This issue seems to alter the perceived structure of the mathematical expression and could lead to misinterpretations.
Observed Problem: When rendering complex mathematical expressions with multiple levels of nested parentheses, such as 1 + 2 * (3 * (5 + 3)), the output in HTML omits some parentheses or displays them incorrectly, resulting in an output like 1 + 2 * 3 * 5 + 3 instead of maintaining all original parentheses.
Temporary Solution Found: I discovered that using the brackets function from the latexexpr_efficalc package, I can enforce the correct display of parentheses. For example:
from latexexpr_efficalc import brackets
    As_req2 = Calculation(
        "As2_{req}", 
        (1+2*brackets(3*brackets(5+3))), 
        "cm^2"
    )

Question: Is using the brackets function the recommended or standard practice when working with Efficalc to ensure parentheses are rendered correctly? It seems there is no mention of this function in the official Efficalc documentation I have accessed. Should the documentation be updated to include brackets as a necessary tool for handling nested mathematical expressions properly?
